# Using SSL/basic authentication and headers appear visible when I view posts on fiddler. Why?

Tags: c#, basic-authentication, webrequest

I am using SSL on the Azure platform (provided out of the box) with basic authentication.  The call works, but when I view the posts on fiddler, I see the authentication string and any other manual headers I add in what appears clear text. Should this be the case?  From what I have read, SSL with basic authentication is an accepted standard and everything should be encrypted.

Using an https url, I see two fiddler entries...the one that tunnels into HTTPS and then a second one.  On the second one (https), I can see the three header items the code adds.   I would have thought it would be encrypted.  Or can I see it on fiddler because the request originated from my machine?

My code looks like this:

```
var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(azureSiteContract);
webRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(user + ":" + pass));
webRequest.Headers["Test"] = "blah1";
webRequest.Headers["Test2"] = "blah2";
webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
using (var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
{
    using (var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
        results = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have probably set fiddler to decrypt using its certificate man in the middle attack.

Comment: The question is why is it decrypting, the answer is because you have probably configured it to do so. I do not see how this is not an answer. Should this be the case, If my stated assumption is true: yes, and yes again to the final question. Your complaint is probably against the question if you do not like this answer. It probably could of been rtfm

Comment: I understand now, and I agree with your assessment. Please consider adding how to check and change decryption settings in Fiddler.

Comment: Most likely that is the case.  I will accept it as so as it is the one thing I hadn't thought of.  If I discover differently, I will post back.  Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: Also...been a while since I used this site.  I will be more punctual checking any answers I post in the future :)

Comment: no worries i have an answer I have not marked correct that's 2 days old .. had no time to check it yet ;)

Comment: Ok...using these instructions (see below), I confirmed John's answer.  Thanks!    http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/decrypthttps/